# React native billing version not supported

Tags: reactjs, react-native, billing

I am trying to use react native billing library v3, but on uploading build to google play console getting an error of version not supported.

Here are the build configurations that I am using :

```
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 30
```

Answer (score 3):

For my case, adding the permission `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />` in my android manifest file caused this error.
So I removed it, then in my `android\app\build.gradle` I added the following, in the `dependencies` block and it worked:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:4.0.0'
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate

> Starting on August 2, 2022, all new apps must use Billing Library
> version 4 or newer. By November 1, 2022, all updates to existing apps
> must use Billing Library version 4 or newer.

Try alternative library for billing integration.
For example:

- https://github.com/dooboolab/react-native-iap
- https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/in-app-purchases/
- https://github.com/RevenueCat/react-native-purchases
- https://github.com/adaptyteam/AdaptySDK-React-Native